# Reset or Uninstall Yosemite Server

Tags: macos, server.app, apache

I installed Yosemite Server and I had previously configured the Apache for web development. Now, It seems that the configuration and everything is messed up.

How can I reset my web server configuration to factory settings, like after installing a fresh Yosemite?

Does an uninstall of Yosemite Server affects my current web server configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset just the Websites service in OS X Server with the following command:

```
sudo serveradmin command web:command=restoreFactorySettings
```

Make sure the Websites and Wiki services are off when you run this command.

Uninstalling OS X Server will, by default, retain all configuration files so that reinstallation keeps all data, however you can delete the Server folder to reset all the data.